# Does Tom Riddle/ Lord Voldemort remember the Chamber of Secrets Incident?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, hogwarts, horcrux

I was rewatching the movies and was wondering if Voldemort remembered his encounter with Harry in the Chamber of Secrets since he makes no mention of it when he gains his body again in Little Hangleton and neither in the upcoming meetings both rivals have throughout the books and movies. So would it make sense that Voldemort wasn't aware that his teenage diary was destroyed by Harry?

Comment: Tom Riddle in the Chamber of Secrets was just a memory of a younger Voldemort, not Voldemort himself

Answer (score 5):

## No - the Dark Lord didn’t know Harry found the diary until later.

The Dark Lord had no memory of his Horcrux interacting with Harry. He only learned afterwards, by questioning Lucius Malfoy, that Harry had found the diary and destroyed it.

> “Perhaps, at the point of death, he might be aware of his loss … but he was not aware, for instance, that the diary had been destroyed until he forced the truth out of Lucius Malfoy. When Voldemort discovered that the diary had been mutilated and robbed of all its powers, I am told that his anger was terrible to behold.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23 (Horcruxes)*</sup></sub>

If he’d remembered his Horcrux’s interaction with Harry, then he’d also be aware it was destroyed.